# Modify Makefile to include a library and use C++11

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, g++

I have the following makefile:

```
VER=cblas
GCC_VERSION = 7.2.0
PREFIX = /usr/local/gcc/${GCC_VERSION}/bin/
CC = ${PREFIX}gcc
CPP = ${PREFIX}g++

w2.${VER}: w2.${VER}.o
    $(CPP) -ow2.${VER} w2.${VER}.o

w2.${VER}.o: w2.${VER}.cpp
    $(CPP) -c -O2 -std=c++17 w2.${VER}.cpp 

clean:
    rm *.o
```

I need to modify this makefile such that it will include the gsl library. I was able compile directly with the commands:

```
g++ -Wall -I/home/path/gsl/include -c w2.cblas.cpp
g++ -L/home/path/gsl/lib w2.cblas.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

How can I modify this makefile to include the gsl library (and c++11)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of defining your own rules (i.e.: remove the following):

```
w2.${VER}: w2.${VER}.o
    $(CPP) -ow2.${VER} w2.${VER}.o

w2.${VER}.o: w2.${VER}.cpp
    $(CPP) -c -O2 -std=c++17 w2.${VER}.cpp
```

you can simply rely on the already-defined implicit rules.
You just have to properly set up the variables these implicit rules work with.
Therefore, in order to find the header files for the compilation:

```
CPPFLAGS := -I/home/path/gsl/include
```

For the optimization and the specification of the C++ standard:

```
CXXFLAGS := -O2 -std=c++11
```

Finally, for the linking:

```
LDFLAGS := -L/home/path/gsl/lib
LDLIBS := -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
LD = $(CXX)
```

---

Note that those rules rely on the `CXX` variable for specifying the compiler and not  `CPP`, so you don't want:

```
CPP = ${PREFIX}g++
```

but:

```
CXX = ${PREFIX}g++
```

By the way, `CPP` in make stands for *C Pre-Processor* (and not *C++*, that would be `CXX`).

---

#### Makefile

Putting everything explained above together, your makefile would then look like the following:

```
ER=cblas
GCC_VERSION = 7.2.0
PREFIX = /usr/local/gcc/${GCC_VERSION}/bin/

CC = ${PREFIX}gcc
CXX = ${PREFIX}g++

CPPFLAGS := -I/home/path/gsl/include
CXXFLAGS := -O2 -std=c++11

LDFLAGS := -L/home/path/gsl/lib
LDLIBS := -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
LD = $(CXX)

clean:
    rm *.o
```

Note that `clean` is the only *explicit rule* in the makefile above.

Considering that you have source file called `w2.cblas.cpp`, then you should call `make` this way:

```
make w2.cblas
```

Comment: Don’t forget to set `CXX` (*and `LD`*)! `CPP` isn’t what OP wants. And the object file shouldn’t be mentioned in the `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: I attempted to include the changes in the makefile (see edit) and it compiled, and the library seems to have linked but I also got an error message  (edit).

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Try to remove your two rules `w2.${VER}` and `w2.${VER}.o`.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 I tried that but it didn't work. Without those two lines there are no targets? Not sure if I understand what you mean.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer How are you calling `make` ? The rules to use are implicit.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer not two lines, but four. The snippet at the very beginning of my post is what I would like you to remove.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer and there was a problem with `LDFLAGS` and the C++ standard (it was C++17) as well (see my updated post).

Comment: When I remove those lines of code and run 'make' it returns *** No targets. Stop. When I run 'make w2.mblas.cpp' it returns 'Nothing to be done for w2.mblas.cpp`

Comment: @bigcodeszzer ok, try running `make w2.mblas` (that is, without the `.cpp`).

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164470/discussion-between--and-bigcodeszzer).